# How to have consistency between rails and javascript routes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes

I was getting a little tired of seeing this sort of thing:

```
$('#events').load('/user/' + user.id + '/events?limit=' + limit);
```

Strewn throughout my code when I had nice rails routes like `user_events_path(user)` to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's a nice plugin called [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/) that allows you to reuse your routes like this:

```
Routes.user_events_path({user_id: user.id})
```

Comment: do you post questions when you have the answer?

Comment: It is odd that all of his questions were answered by himself instantly.

Comment: @RobH stackoverflow would be some new notebook :)

Comment: When I find something useful that I don't see on stackoverflow I add it so others might benefit from it.  Stackoverflow actually encourages this behavior by having an "answer your own question" checkbox when you post one.  Am I doing something wrong?